Proving a linear functional belongs to $L^{4/3}(0,T; H^{-1})$
Let $H^{-1}$ be the dual to the Sobolev space $H^1$ and $T > 0$. Let $u: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $u \in L^\infty(0,T; L^2) \cap L^2(0,T; H^1)$. It can be shown that $$(u \cdot \nabla) u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; L^{6/5}). \tag{1}$$ Let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ and define a linear functional $g \in H^{-1}$ as follows:
$$\langle g, \varphi\rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1} = -\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle - \langle (u \cdot \nabla) u, \varphi\rangle.$$
In the book The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations by Robinson, Rodrigo, and Sadowski, they first note that
$$| \langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi\rangle| \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}\|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2} \tag{2}$$
and
$$|\langle(u \cdot \nabla) u, \varphi \rangle| \leq \|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}}\|\varphi\|_{L^6} \leq C  \|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}} \|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2} \tag{3}$$
which they claim by (1) implies
$$\|g\|^{4/3}_{H^{-1}} \leq C  \|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + C\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2} \\\leq C  \|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + C(1 + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2}) \in L^1(0,T)$$
and hence $g \in L^{4/3}(0,T; H^{-1})$.
I understand that they obtained (2) and (3) by using the Holder and the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequalities, but how did they estimate $\|g\|_{H^{-1}}$? Shouldn't dual norms always have a supremum? What was the need to bound $\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2}$ by $(1 + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2})$ and how was this bound achieved?

To estimate $\|g\|_{H^{-1}}$ they (silently) took the supremum of the upper bounds of $\langle g,\phi\rangle$ over all $\phi$ with $\|\phi\|_{H^1} \le 1$, that is how the $\phi$-related terms disappeared.
In my opinion, there is a $\nabla$-operator missing originating from (2), it should read
$$
\|g\|_{H^{-1}} \le c \|(u\cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}} + c \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}.
$$

Thank you for your answer and for catching that typo, I have updated my post. I now understand how they established that $$|g|{H^{-1}} \le c |(u\cdot \nabla) u|{L^{6/5}} +  |\nabla u|{L^2}$$ but raising both sides to $4/3$ power we would get $$|g|{H^{-1}}^{4/3} \le \Big(c |(u\cdot \nabla) u|{L^{6/5}} +  |\nabla u|{L^2}\Big)^{4/3}.$$ How do they neglect the cross terms to get the exponent on each norm individually? And why does the term $|\nabla u|_{L^2}$ have a constant in front?

I am guessing the constant comes form taking the supremum since the inequality has $|\nabla \varphi|{L^2}$ and not just $|\varphi|{L^2}$?

@CBBAM $x\mapsto \vert x \vert^p$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}_+$ for $p > 1$, hence $\vert a + b \vert^p \leq 2^{p-1}(\vert a \vert^p + \vert b \vert^p)$. Here, $p = \frac{4}{3}$.

@stange Thank you! I think I almost have this fully understood. The last part I was struggling with was how they bounded $|u|^{4/3}{L^2}$ by $(1 + |\nabla u|^2{L^2})$

@CBBAM This follows from Youngs inequality. When you have term like $a^p$, you can always go to a higher power $a^q$ with $q \geq p$ but have to pay the price of an additional constant

@stange I see. So you are using Young's inequality $$ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q}$$ with $a = |\nabla u|^{4/3}$, $b = 1$, $p= 3/2$ and $q = 3$?

@CBBAM Yes, that's correct

@stange Thanks for all the help!
